# Calling A Button OnClick from a function

Tags: c#, asp.net, function, button, onclick

I have a button with OnClick=Button_Click. I want to call Button_Click from another function but the problem is that I need to give it:

```
(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

What should I enter for those parameters? Is there any way around it?

Comment: You talking about javascript or ASP.Net C# because OnClick event is for client side script not server side

Comment: I think he talks about server click event which is attached to button. You can easily determine by underscore convention

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this

```
 Button_Click(null,EventArgs.Empty);
```

although I agree that it's better to extract function that could be called from anywhere.

For example if you have

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //some list of code      
}
```

this code should be put in some new method and then called from Button_Click or any other method

```
private void ExtractedMethod()
{ 
 //some list of code
}

 protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  ExtractedMethod();    
 }
```

I recommend you to read a book ***Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code*** by *Martin Fowler*. It's a must on a shelf. You will come back to that book from time to time, it's timeless.

Comment: +1 for **Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code** ;)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if the action is done primarily by the button, or to avoid extra methods, as of .Net 4.0, there is a function called .PerformClick(). So

`Button.PerformClick();`

Would execute the button click from inside the code.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the functionality that you have within the "onclick" into another function. You can then call it from anywhere, including the onClick.