# How to give button click event automatically

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling A Button OnClick from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130584/calling-a-button-onclick-from-a-function)

I want to do button click event automatically .I want code for button click event without manual clicking of the button.

Comment: Do u mean some thing like UIautomation or calling the event???

Comment: This sounds like a design problem rather than a serious requirement. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to win the lottery.  Oh wait - I forgot to mention what I tried - I went to the store, bought 20 tickets, used random numbers - but still didn't win anything.  What could I try next?   Can you see the correlation between this and your question?  Please tell us what you have tried so we can try to help you....

Comment: WinForms, ASP.NET, GTK#, WPF...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for [Button.PerformClick()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx);

```
button1.PerformClick();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two things to say:

- You should modify your applications to use IObservables for the events in such a way that you can mock the events allowing for better testing.
- If you want to automate UI interaction, [There is a DLL for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1364684/402022) thanks to [DataDink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152062/datadink)